# What does `setTextRange` do and when is it necessary when writing TypeScript transforms?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

Here's a snippet I found on the Internet! It changes the `SourceFile` `statements` but it does so via a `setTextRange` call which I don't understand why it is needed or what it's intended purpose is. It's not syntax...

```
return ts.updateSourceFileNode(
  sf,
  ts.setTextRange(
    ts.createNodeArray([
      ...sf.statements.slice(0, firstHoistableNodeIndex + 1),
      // Inject hoisted variables
      ...hoistedVariables,
      ...transformedStatements
    ]),
    sf.statements
  )
);
```

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/madou/typescript-transformer-handbook) for tips and tricks regarding writing TypeScript transforms

Comment: Apparently, TypeScript made [some changes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commits/189e883cb9bef106a5e9163917f5463c2d2c272d/src/compat/deprecations.ts) to some of these APIs very recently.